# WFS 1.1 - How to flip order of latitude and longitude in the response from Boundless Geoserver

Tags: wfs

Please see the attached image. It shows a wfs 1.1 request and response. In the image I have indicated what I am trying to achieve in Red arrow. The coordinates array in the response has longitude first. But I need Latitude as the first item in the coordinates array in the response. Can anyone suggest me how to achieve that

[image]

Comment: please copy and paste textual data into your question rather than using a screen shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use GeoJSON as output as you seem to do, you can't have latitude first. In GeoJSON only longitude-latitude order is allowed http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html.

> A position is represented by an array of numbers. There must be at
>   least two elements, and may be more. The order of elements must follow
>   x, y, z order (easting, northing, altitude for coordinates in a
>   projected coordinate reference system, or longitude, latitude,
>   altitude for coordinates in a geographic coordinate reference system).

You must change your process to deal with GeoJSON properly or use the default GML3 format of WFS 1.1.0.